# How to covert Namespace PHP to JSON

Tags: php, json

I have the following scenario:

```
$class = 'Main\Entity\Redaction'; #or anything else namespaced class
$nameClass = explode('\\', $class);
$jsonNamespace = [];
if (!empty($nameClass[0])) {
    $jsonNamespace[$nameClass[0]] = [];
    if (!empty($nameClass[1])) {
        $jsonNamespace[$nameClass[0]][$nameClass[1]] = [];
        if (!empty($nameClass[2])) {
            $jsonNamespace[$nameClass[0]][$nameClass[1]][$nameClass[2]] = ['#wherever'];
        }
    }
}
```

I want to declare a namespaced object JSON.
Something like this:

```
{
     Main: {
          Entity: {
               Redaction: ['#wherever']
          }
     }
}
```

But without a lot of "IF", something recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with recursion, but another way is by using a reference.  Add a new level to the array, and then simply shift the reference down to that new element.

```
<?php
function buildArray(array $keys, $value){
    $ret = array();
    $ref =& $ret;

    foreach($keys as $key){
        // Add the next level to the array
        $ref[$key] = array();
        // Then shift the reference, so that the next
        // iteration can add a new level
        $ref =& $ref[$key];
    }

    // $ref is a reference to the lowest level added
    $ref = array($value);

    // Not totally sure if this is needed
    unset($ref);

    return $ret;
}

$class = 'Main\Entity\Redaction';
$jsonNamespace = buildArray(explode('\\', $class), array('#wherever'));

var_dump($jsonNamespace);
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/f7O0Qy3D